# Is switch statement the same as if statement in this specific code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand whether a specific `switch` statement is equivalent to this `if` statement.

```
if (killstreak == 1) //If killstreak is 1, give one throwing knife and write Mr. Kniferino on screen.
        {
            attacker.GiveWeapon("throwingknife_mp");
            attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^2Mr. Kniferino");
            attacker.SetPerk("specialty_scavenger", true, false);
        }
        if (killstreak == 2) //If killstreak is 3, give 10 bullets and write You've received 10 bullets on screen.
        {
            attacker.Call("setweaponammoclip", "iw5_fnfiveseven_mp_tactical", 8);
            attacker.Call("setweaponammostock", "iw5_fnfiveseven_mp_tactical", 0);
            attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^2You've received 10 ^1bullets");
        }
        if (killstreak == 3) //If killstreak is 2, give Scavenger and write Scavenger on screen.
        {
            AfterDelay(10, () =>
            attacker.SetPerk("specialty_scavenger", true, true));
            attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^4Scavenger");
        }
```

So would this `if` statement be equivalent to this `switch` statement?

```
switch (killstreak)
        {
            case 1:
                attacker.GiveWeapon("throwingknife_mp");
                attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^2Mr. Kniferino");
                attacker.SetPerk("specialty_scavenger", true, false);
            break;
            case 2:
                attacker.Call("setweaponammoclip", "iw5_fnfiveseven_mp_tactical", 8);
                attacker.Call("setweaponammostock", "iw5_fnfiveseven_mp_tactical", 0);
                attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^2You've received 10 ^1bullets");
            break;
            case 3:
                AfterDelay(10, () =>
                attacker.SetPerk("specialty_scavenger", true, true));
                attacker.Call("iprintlnBold", "^4Scavenger");
            break;
        }
```

If something isn't clear, I'll happily explain again.

Comment: switch will never be the same as if statements... It doesn't work the same way

Comment: If you take a TDD approach, your unit tests will answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost, but not quite. The outcome in your case will be the same (so you could say that they are different ways of achieving the same logic). The difference is that your `if` statement tests would all be executed, while the switch would only evaluate once, than branch to the appropriate case.

You could add `else` statements to terminate early but still there is a fundamental difference between `switch` statements and `if/else` chains. The latter give you more flexibility, while the `switch` could technically, be optimized by the compiler into a branch table, and the condition (if it's an expression) will only be evaluated once.

This would be *more like* a switch statement but still, not exactly the same:

```
if (killstreak == 1)
{
     /* case 1 */
}
else if (killstreak == 2)     // only tested if killstreak != 1
{
     /* case 2 */
}
else if (killstreak == 3)     // only tested if killstreak != 1 and != 2
{
    /* case 3 */
}
```

But as I said, this is still not entirely the same. A switch statement may be translated by the compiler into equivalent code to the `if/else` chain above, but it could be translated into a lookup table too, something more like this:

```
BranchTable = [CASE1_ADDR, CASE2_ADDR, CASE3_ADDR]

goto BranchTable[killstreak]

CASE1_ADDR:
       /* code for test 1*/
       goto AFTER_SWITCH_ADDR;   
CASE2_ADDR:
       /* code for test 2*/
       goto AFTER_SWITCH_ADDR;   
CASE3_ADDR:
       /* code for test 3*/           
AFTER_SWITCH_ADDR:
       /* code following swtich statement */
```

Comment: `the switch could technically, be optimized by the compiler into a branch table` Not only does this happen in practice, the compiler can do other optimizations, such as using a dictionary-based implementation (as it does when the `switch` values are strings and there are enough cases to make it a worthwhile improvement over just a series of comparisons). Of course, the compiler _could_ detect a switch-like implementation that uses if/else if/else and convert _that_ as an optimization. So even these distinctions are somewhat arbitrary. For me, it's about which one expresses intent better.

Comment: So this brings me to another question. In the 'if statement', I told the code that 'if killstreak == 1', to execute a specific block of code. I want to know how to write 'killstreak == 1' in switch, for example. Where exactly does it tell the compiler that if the 'killstreak == 1' to run a specific code in switch? As far as I know, the case: 1 is only an identifier name - not the actual code telling the compiler to check whether 'killstreak == 1'. Thank you for the help! This answer actually helped me a lot. @Mike Dinescu

Comment: @user3713606, I'm not sure what you mean. Essentially, writing `switch(killstreak) { case 1: { /* do something */ break; } }` pretty much does what you wanted: it evaluates `killstreak` and if it's value is `1` it will execute the /* do something */ code..

Comment: @MikeDinescu but if I write it like that, when a player kills someone, his killstreak would go up one which mean it will be 1, however, I want that if it reaches 1, it gives the player something and when he reaches 2, it would give the player another thing. Is that possible in the switch code I wrote on top?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really not sure what you're trying to say. I think it might be better to just try it out. Write simple code that simulates what you'd like to accomplish and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, yes, it's the same, given that 1 can never equal 2 or 3. killstreak is always going to be equal to one of those and not the others.

But logically, the construction you've made here differs in an important way. switch statements in C# are more identical to if/else-if/else (with default) than they are to if/if/if. `break` prevents the control flow from passing any further upon the first time you encounter a case that evaluates to true, whereas every single one of your if statements will always be evaluated.

For example, if you accidentally hit the wrong key when constructing your second conditional:

```
if (killstreak == 1)
{
    FunctionOne();
}
// should have been 2
if (killstreak == 1)
{
    FunctionTwo();
}
```

both FunctionOne() and FunctionTwo() would execute, because those two conditionals are logically independent of one another. The result of one has no bearing on whether the next is executed.

(Edit: it's been pointed out that there's not really a way at all to have two identical cases in switch statements. They require either literals or constants, and will fail to compile if the same value is used for multiple cases. I've removed that portion.)

An easy way to deal with this in terms of if blocks where you only ever want one portion of code to execute is using else if:

```
if (killstreak == 1)
{
    FunctionOne();
}
else if (killstreak == 1)
{
    FunctionTwo();
}
```

This would execute identically to the example switch statement above - only FunctionOne() would ever be executed. Your typo no longer causes two separate killstreak actions to execute each time the user gets a single kill.

Edit: Namfuak points out another possibility - if somehow killstreak was incremented within FunctionOne(), when execution came to the second if block below, FunctionTwo() would also execute.

```
// killstreak is 1
if (killstreak == 1)
{
    // will execute
    FunctionOne(); // increments killstreak
}
// killstreak is 2
if (killstreak == 2)
{
    // will also execute
    FunctionTwo();
}
```

Comment: Another possibility is that if he increments `killstreak`, it could evaluate to `1`, `2`, and so on, whereas in a switch it will only evaluate once even if it is changed in the block.

Comment: `switch (killstreak) { case 1: ...; case 1: ...; }` would fail to compile.

Comment: @hvd I was actually just to checking that - I'm going back to include a more real-world use case with variables anyway.

Comment: Well, I could of done if/else if/else statement but I wanted to make a different action happen every time. For example, when killstreak == 1 - give throwing knife. If killstreak == 2, give ammunition for weapon. I want all of this to happen, but, I want to use it in a switch statement, if possible. @furkle

Comment: @user3713606 Oh, I'm not telling you whether you should use the switch statement or not - a lot of my point is that it's good to use if/else if for outcomes you'd like to be mutually exclusive, rather than if/if/if/etc. A switch statement would work perfectly fine for that, and your switch statement above looks fine.

Comment: So, @furkle , if you wanted to write the if statement that I wrote in a switch format, how would you write it? I'm guessing it wouldn't be the same way I wrote it.

Comment: @user3713606 I really wouldn't change much at all - the only thing I'd change is that I'd write `if (killstreak == 1) {}` `else if (killstreak == 2) {}` `else if (killstreak == 3) {}` etc. It's a minor change, but overall I think it's a safer pattern.

Comment: @furkle At the end, I want all of them to happen. Everytime a person kills someone in the game, his killstreak will go up one. If I use else if I will never reach killstreak 2 or 3, would I?

Comment: @user3713606 You would - presumably (probably necessarily, unless I'm missing something about C# in general) you're calling the method that evaluates killstreak each time a kill is made. Any code within a method is executed every time that method is called - the fact that if (killstreak == 1) evaluated as true the first time you called, for example, `doKillstreak()` doesn't have any bearing on how the conditionals within that method will be executed the next time you call it.

Comment: @furkle I get it now! That makes a lot of sense. So would the switch statement that I wrote work in the same way? I mean, is the switch statement correct?

Comment: @user3713606 Yeah, your switch statement works perfectly great. A lot of people here wrote a lot (probably too much in my case) going into why the two statements you wrote are slightly different logically, even though the code you've provided will execute the same way.

Comment: @furkle What you wrote helped me a lot! All your explanations gave me a better overview of what I wrote. I know I'm not really supposed to write 'thanks' or '+1', however, you did such an incredible job explaining, I had to say thank you.